# Concurrency issues with QThreads. Threads receiving the same signal are blocking each other

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, concurrency, qthread

So I'm working on a program that processes video in real-time and I'm having some trouble with threads "blocking" each other.

My system is pretty much set up like this:

```
         DataSourceThread
             /      \
            /        \
           /          \
     Receiver       Receiver
         /              \
        /                \ 
       /                  \
 Processor1            Processor2
```

(All these classes are extending QThread.)

So DataSourceThread fetches frames from a videostream and emits a signal containing the frame to the receivers. **Connection type: Qt::DirectConnection**

The receivers basically receive the the frames sent out by DataSourceThread and if the Processor is done processing the previous frame, it will emit a signal containing the frame to the Processor. **Connection type: Qt::QueuedConnection.**
If the processor is not done processing the previous frame, it will just return without emitting a signal (skipping frames).

To test if this works, all I've done is have Processor1 just print out a message when it receives a frame and Processor2 does *QThread::sleep(3);* and print out a message.

(The receivers will also do a deep copy of the frame before passing it on to the processors.)

**Expected result:**

Processor1 should be constantly printing messages.
Processor2 should be printing a message every 3 seconds.

**The problem:**

Both processors print their messages at the same time (every 3 seconds).
Processor1 waits until Processor2 is done before printing its message.
So the output is pretty much like this:

```
"Message from processor1"
"Message from processor2"
"Message from processor1"
"Message from processor2"
"Message from processor1"
"Message from processor2"
```

and so on.

I'm running out of ideas here,
so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Here's some of the code:

**main.cpp:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    DataSourceThread dataSourceThread;
    dataSourceThread.start();

    GUIThread *guiProcessor = new GUIThread();
    FrameReceiver *guiReceiver = new FrameReceiver(guiProcessor, 0);

    QObject::connect(
        &dataSourceThread, SIGNAL(frameReceived(Frame*)),
        guiReceiver, SLOT(receive(Frame*)),
        Qt::DirectConnection
    );

    DetectorThread *detectorProcessor = new DetectorThread();
    FrameReceiver *detectorReceiver = new FrameReceiver(detectorProcessor, 0);

    QObject::connect(
        &dataSourceThread, SIGNAL(frameReceived(Frame*)),
        detectorReceiver, SLOT(receive(Frame*)),
        Qt::DirectConnection
    );

    return app.exec();
}
```

**From DataSourceThread.cpp:**

```
void DataSourceThread::run()
{
    ... stuff ...

    while (true) {
        image = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        if (!image) { 
            qDebug() << QString("Could not capture frame"); 
            continue;
        }

        cvReleaseImage(&temp_image);
        temp_image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), image->depth, 3);

        cvResize(image, temp_image, 1);

        frame->lock();
        frame->setImage(temp_image);
        frame->unlock();

        emit frameReceived(frame);

        msleep(1); 
    }
}
```

**FrameReceiver.cpp:**

```
FrameReceiver::FrameReceiver(FrameProcessor* processor, QObject *parent) : QThread(parent) {
    m_ready = true;

    m_processor = processor;
    m_processor->start();

    QObject::connect(
        (QObject*)this, SIGNAL(frameReceived(Frame*)),
        m_processor, SLOT(receive(Frame*)), 
        Qt::QueuedConnection
    );

    QObject::connect(
        m_processor, SIGNAL(ready()),
        (QObject*)this, SLOT(processCompleted()),
        Qt::DirectConnection
    ); }

void FrameReceiver::processCompleted() {
    m_ready = true; }

void FrameReceiver::receive(Frame *frame) {
    if (m_ready == true) {
        m_ready = false;
        frame->lock();
        Frame *f = new Frame(*frame);
        frame->unlock();
        emit frameReceived(f);
    } else {
        // SKIPPED THIS FRAME
    }
}
```

**GUIThread.cpp: (Processor1)**

```
GUIThread::GUIThread(QObject *parent) : FrameProcessor(parent)
{
    m_frame = new Frame();
}

void GUIThread::setFrame(Frame *frame)
{ 
    qDebug() << QString("Guithread received frame");
}
```

**FrameProcessor.cpp**

```
// (The processors extend this class)
void FrameProcessor::receive(Frame *frame)
 {
     setFrame(frame);
     delete frame;
     emit ready();
 }
```

**DetectorThread (Processor2)** does the same as guithread, but with a 3 sec sleep in setFrame.

Comment: In my DataSourceThread I do: emit frameReceived(frame); and in the receiver I copy the frame and do: emit frameReceived(copied_frame);

Comment: Does FrameProcessor inherit from QThread? If so, did you override run() or does it use the default implementation?

Comment: FrameProcessor does indeed inherit from QThread, but does not override run()

Comment: Are you calling QThread::moveToThread() anywhere?

Comment: Nope, the code I've posted here should have all the thread related code in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think part of the problem is that all of your QObjects are owned by the main application thread. This means they all share a one event loop for delivering asynchronous signals, effectively serializing your whole processing chain.

I think the proper way to set this up would be something like:

```
GUIProcessor *guiProcessor = new GUIProcessor();
QThread guiProcessorThread;
guiProcessor.moveToThread(&guiProcessorThread);

FrameReceiver *guiReceiver = new FrameReceiver(guiProcessor, 0);
QThread guiReceiverThread;
guiReceiver.moveToThread(&guiReceiverThread);

guiProcessorThread.start();
guiReceiverThread.start();
```

If you do it this way I would suggest not using `DirectConnection` between threads, but rather `BlockingQueuedConnection` if you want to ensure that the current frame is processed before you capture the next one.

See this: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

And this: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2006/12/04/threading-without-the-headache/

Hope this helps!

EDIT: To be clear, with my suggestion your classes would inherit QObject instead of QThread.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a real lifesaver! Your suggestion worked like a charm!